# Не работает система реактивности Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

В mounted устанавливаю значение abilities. На странице должны выводится данные из этого свойства, но ничего не выводится. Попробовала вывести это свойство целиком на странице - вывелись пустые фигурные скобки. Хотя если посмотреть во Vue Developer, это свойство правильно изменилось.

```
data() {
    return {
        pokemonInfo: null,
        abilities: null,
        ready: false
    }
},
mounted: function () {
    var id = this.$router.currentRoute.path.slice(1);
    var abili = {};
    this.$axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)
        .then((response) => {
            this.pokemonInfo = response.data
            for (let i = 0; i < this.pokemonInfo.abilities.length; i++) {
                this.$axios.get(this.pokemonInfo.abilities[i].ability.url)
                    .then((response) => {
                        abili[i] = response.data;
                    })
            }
            this.abilities = abili;
            this.ready = true;
        })
},
```

Вот тут вот данные должны выводится, выше это завернуто в блок с  v-if="ready"

```
<h2>Abilities:</h2>
<p v-for="(item, index) in abilities">{{abilities[index].ability.name}}</p>
<p>{{abilities}}</p>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Открываем https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html и читаем.

Comment: Читала, все равно не поняла почему не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) abilities у вас объект, а по факту это массив. Так пусть массивом и будет.

2) У вас есть вложенный запрос, которые вызываются параллельно и по результату выполнения записываются в некий `abili`, но основной контекст выполнения результат не ждет и сразу ассайнит пустой объект в `abilities`.

В результате должно получиться так [(пример здесь)](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-b8zdt):

```
  mounted: function() {
    this.$axios
      .get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2`)
      .then(response => {
        this.pokemonInfo = response.data;
        const abilityRequests = this.pokemonInfo.abilities.map((el, index) => {
          return this.$axios.get(this.pokemonInfo.abilities[index].ability.url);
        });
        Promise.all(abilityRequests).then((abilities) => {
          this.abilities = abilities.map(response => response.data);;
          this.ready = true;
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Спаибо огромное